# How to rebuild data combination Power Query

Tags: powerquery

In Power Query, I want to use a list of distinct values from one query (e.g. list of customers present on "Sales" table), to inject it on a SQL statement on another query (e.g. "Customer" dimensional table).

To pull the list of distinct values I have a function, getDistinct() that:

1. Retrieves one column from a query choice,
2. Only keep distinct values present on that column, and
3. Return these distinct values separated by commas so they can be injected within an SQL statement.

This function works fine on a standalone query. However, when I try to use it on my "Customer" query it throws an error (see code and error below):

```
let
    Source = Oracle.Database("myServer", [Query="select * from db_customer where customer_id in (" & getDistinct(Sales,"CustomerID") & ")"])
in
    Source
```

And the error:

> Formula.Firewall: Query 'Customer' (step 'Source') references
>   other queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source.
>   Please rebuild this data combination.

I've tried creating a different query that executes the function and then referencing it on my "Customer" query, but this doesn't seem to work. I know I can "Ignore Privacy Levels" (which by the way, I've checked and works), but since I don't know the implications of it, I'm afraid of leaked data.

Comment: for "I don't know the implications of it, I'm afraid of leaked data" see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/dataprivacyfirewall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why a function or any hand-written code is necessary for this requirement.

I would create a Query to get the Sales table and then Group by CustomerID. I would set that to: Load To / Only Create Connection.

Then the Customers Query would just be:

1. Source is Oracle Customers table
2. Merge to Sales Query on CustomerID, with Join Kind = Inner

Comment: This doesn't work for me. If on step 1 you fetch all customer data, any power user will be able to open Power Query and see all customer data.

Comment: If they wanted to access it they could change the query in the first answer to get it. If you create the source query as a connection only users shouldn't be able to see any of the source data on the worksheet.

Comment: @AlejandroLopez-Lago-MSFT I may not have described correctly the specific scenario. Let's say I want to share this report with a particular audience (that can't refresh the report since they don't have access to the database) and I don't want them to access in any way customer data that's not present on the sales table. Unless I'm missing something, even if I create a "connection only" query, you can still go to PowerQuery and see a preview of the data, which might end up being data that they should not see even if it's not loaded into the model.

Comment: The preview isn't saved to the workbook. If users who do not have permissions to the database go to any of the steps, they will only see a yellow bar asking them to enter their credentials. Once they enter them, Power Query will get data from the database using their credentials. 
However, if you fill the data to the worksheet or data model,then the final result is saved with the document, and the data would be visible there.

Comment: @Victor - if data security is your concern, consider that any power user would also be able to use generic Excel Get External Data or many other tools besides PQ to access Oracle.